# Getting a "Specified cast is not valid" error

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Trace Log:
7/26/2023 1:09:54 PM Error:
Specified cast is not valid.

at _SetValueByOrdinal(RCContractPayment , Int32 , Object , PXCacheExtension[] )
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.SetValue(Object data, Int32 ordinal, Object value) at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation) at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation) at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist() at PX.Data.PXSave`1.d__2.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__38.MoveNext() at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__38.MoveNext()
at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows)
at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
DAC:

```
[Serializable]
    [PXCacheName("RCContractPayment")]
    public class RCContractPayment : IBqlTable
    {
        #region ContractID
        [RoyaltyContract(IsKey = true)]
        [PXDBDefault(typeof(RCContract.contractID))]
        [PXParent(typeof(SelectFrom<RCContract>.
                    Where<RCContract.contractID.
                        IsEqual<RCContractPayment.contractID.FromCurrent>>))]
        public virtual int? ContractID { get; set; }
        public abstract class contractID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<contractID> { }
        #endregion

        #region LineNbr
        [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
        [PXDefault]
        [PXLineNbr(typeof(RCContract.paymentLineCntr))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Line Nbr")]
        public virtual int? LineNbr { get; set; }
        public abstract class lineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<lineNbr> { }
        #endregion

        #region PaymentType
        [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment Type")]
        [PXStringList(
            new string[]
            {
                Constants.ContractPaymentTypeConstants.Bonus,
                Constants.ContractPaymentTypeConstants.Contract,
                Constants.ContractPaymentTypeConstants.RoyaltyPrepayment
            },
            new string[]
            {
                Constants.RoyaltyContractMessages.Bonus,
                Constants.RoyaltyContractMessages.Contract,
                Constants.RoyaltyContractMessages.RoyaltyPrepayment
            })]
        public virtual string PaymentType { get; set; }
        public abstract class paymentType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<paymentType> { }
        #endregion

        #region PaymentClassification
        [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment Classification")]
        [PXStringList(
            new string[]
            {
                Constants.ContractPaymentClassificationConstants.DownPayment,
                Constants.ContractPaymentClassificationConstants.FinalPayment
            },
            new string[]
            {
                Constants.RoyaltyContractMessages.DownPayment,
                Constants.RoyaltyContractMessages.FinalPayment
            })]
        public virtual string PaymentClassification { get; set; }
        public abstract class paymentClassification : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<paymentClassification> { }
        #endregion

        #region PaymentAmount
        [PXDBDecimal()]
        [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
        [PXUIVerify(typeof(Where<RCContractPayment.paymentAmount, GreaterEqual<decimal0>>), PXErrorLevel.Error, RoyaltyContractMessages.PaymentAmountMustBePositive)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment Amount")]
        public virtual Decimal? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
        public abstract class paymentAmount : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<paymentAmount> { }
        #endregion

        #region PaymentTrigger
        [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment Trigger")]
        [RCContractPaymentTriggerTypeListAttribute.List]
        public virtual string PaymentTrigger { get; set; }
        public abstract class paymentTrigger : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<paymentTrigger> { }
        #endregion

        #region EstimatedTriggerDate
        [PXDBDate()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Estimated Trigger Date")]
        public virtual DateTime? EstimatedTriggerDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class estimatedTriggerDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<estimatedTriggerDate> { }
        #endregion

        #region TriggerSalesAmount
        [PXDBDecimal()]
        [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
        [PXUIVerify(typeof(Where<RCContractPayment.triggerSalesAmount, GreaterEqual<decimal0>>), PXErrorLevel.Error, RoyaltyContractMessages.TriggerSalesAmountMustBePositive)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Trigger Sales Amount")]
        public virtual Decimal? TriggerSalesAmount { get; set; }
        public abstract class triggerSalesAmount : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<triggerSalesAmount> { }
        #endregion

        #region TriggerSalesUnits
        [PXDBInt()]
        [PXDefault(0)]
        [PXUIVerify(typeof(Where<RCContractPayment.triggerSalesUnits, GreaterEqual<Zero>>), PXErrorLevel.Error, RoyaltyContractMessages.TriggerSalesUnitsMustBePositive)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Trigger Sales Units")]
        public virtual int? TriggerSalesUnits { get; set; }
        public abstract class triggerSalesUnits : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<triggerSalesUnits> { }
        #endregion

        #region TriggerDate
        [PXDBDate()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Trigger Date")]
        public virtual DateTime? TriggerDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class triggerDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<triggerDate> { }
        #endregion

        #region TriggerAfterDays
        [PXDBInt()]
        [PXDefault(0)]
        [PXUIVerify(typeof(Where<RCContractPayment.triggerAfterDays, GreaterEqual<Zero>>), PXErrorLevel.Error, RoyaltyContractMessages.TriggerAfterDaysMustBePositive)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Trigger After Days")]
        public virtual int? TriggerAfterDays { get; set; }
        public abstract class triggerAfterDays : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<triggerAfterDays> { }
        #endregion

        #region DueDate
        [PXDBDate()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Due Date")]
        public virtual DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class dueDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<dueDate> { }
        #endregion

        #region APProcessed

        [PXDefault(false)]
        [PXDBBool()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payables Processed", TabOrder = -1, IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual bool? APProcessed { get; set; }
        public abstract class aPProcessed : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<aPProcessed> { }

        #endregion

        #region ContractPaymentBatchID

        [PXDBInt()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Royalty Batch ID", IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual int? ContractPaymentBatchID { get; set; }

        public abstract class contractPaymentBatchID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<contractPaymentBatchID>
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedByID
        [PXDBCreatedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdByID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<createdByID> { }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedByScreenID
        [PXDBCreatedByScreenID()]
        public virtual string CreatedByScreenID { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdByScreenID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<createdByScreenID> { }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedDateTime
        [PXDBCreatedDateTime()]
        public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdDateTime : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<createdDateTime> { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedByID
        [PXDBLastModifiedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedByID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<lastModifiedByID> { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedByScreenID
        [PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID()]
        public virtual string LastModifiedByScreenID { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedByScreenID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<lastModifiedByScreenID> { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedDateTime
        [PXDBLastModifiedDateTime()]
        public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<lastModifiedDateTime> { }
        #endregion

        #region Tstamp
        [PXDBTimestamp()]
        public virtual byte[] Tstamp { get; set; }
        public abstract class tstamp : PX.Data.BQL.BqlByteArray.Field<tstamp> { }
        #endregion
```

Any ideas where to even start looking?

Comment: The easiest way to narrow down the possible parts of code causing this issue will be to remove all the PXDefault/PXDBDefault attributes and then start adding them one by one. At some point the issue should start happening again and that will be your troublemaker.

Comment: That definitely pointed me in the right direction, I doing your suggestion I was able to pin point  it to the custom attribute that we had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ended up being the custom attribute that we were using, once I commented out all of the PXDefault's the underlying error revealed itself. So once I added back the PXDefault's and removed the custom attribute everything worked as expected.